# Promise with a variable number of “then”

Tags: javascript, promise

This code works, but I need not hardcode, but dynamically increase the chain.

```
    function myFunc(data) {
      var f = function (data) {
        console.log("test");
    
        if (window.correctionFlag === true) {
          data.prop = 'newValue';
          return $.Deferred().resolve(data);
        }
    
        return data;
      };
    
      var sleep = function (timeout, data) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
    
        if (data.prop) {
          return deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        }, timeout);
        return deferred;
      };
    
      return $.when(data)
        .then(f)
        .then(function (data) {
          return sleep(1000, data);
        })
// N times...............
        .then(f)
        .then(function (data) {
          return sleep(1000, data);
        });
    }
```

But how to add chain dynamically?

```
var p = Promise.resolve();

            for(var i = 0; i < data.waitTimeout; i++) {
                p = p.then(function(data){
                        return sleep(1000, data);
                    }).then(check);
            }

            return $.when(data).then(p);
```

This does not work correctly. It seems there is an error. How to add units in FOR iterations?

Comment: *"This does not work correctly."* In what way? *"It seems there is an error."* ***What*** error? Fundametally, if you want to do these things in series (not parallel), `p = p.then(/*the next thing*/)` is a perfectly good way to do it if you can't use an `async` function.

Comment: you pass `p` (a Promise object) as a parameter of  `.then`. `then` should receive a function as a parameter. not  Promise. you should initialize `p=$.when(data)` , then concat the promises, and return p

Answer (score 0):

This works fine (JQuery):

```
var p = $.when(data);
    
                for(var i = 0; i < data.waitTimeout; i++) {
                    console.log('inFOR');
                    p = p.then(function(data){
                            return sleep(1000, data);
                        }).then(check);
                }
    
                return p;
```